# list of SelectedRows in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have problem getting selected rows from QTableWidget. I have table like this:

```
[id]  [ key ]
 0     test
 1     pass
```

I want to get every row's key values. I tried QTableWidget->selectedIndexes(); but it says it's protected and I can't access that. When I tried QTableWidget->SelectionModel->selectedIndexes, I don't know how to loop through list and get the key values. Do anyone know better way how can I do it?
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you set the selection behavior of your table widget to select *rows*.

You can always access the so-called "selection model" of any item view/widget. `QTableWidget` inherits from `QAbstractItemView`, which gives you [access to this special model](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). This model can tell you the [selected rows](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) as a list of `QModelIndex`, which can then tell you [the row](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmodelindex.html#row). Once you've got them, you can access the [table content](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtablewidget.html#item), in your case the text in the column with index 1 (key column).

```
static const KEY_COLUMN = 1;

QList<QString> selectedKeys;
QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = ui->tableWidget->selectionModel();
foreach(QModelIndex index, selectionModel->selectedRows())
    selectedIDs << ui->tableWidget->item(index->row(), KEY_COLUMN)->text();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm having selectRows by default. Assume we have 2 columns and 2 rows. When we do ui->tableWidget->selectedItems() it gives us 4 items and loop will take longer. I need only to get rows, not the items. This will be a trick, but I need a faster way.

Comment: @OvérFlôwz Oh, I thought it returns only 2 items. Well, let me see what we should do in this case...

Comment: @OvérFlôwz I'm glad I could help :) P.S: For more complex data, consider using the separated model/view approach instead of the widget class, which combines both model and view. At least, you should know the difference between the two approaches. Happy coding!

Comment: @OvérFlôwz This should help you understand the advantage of the approach I'm talking about: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html - Learning to do the things *the good way* from the beginning is better than learning it later. Just my 2 cents. :) Have fun learning Qt!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `QTableWidget`, you probably want to be calling [`selectedItems()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#selectedItems). Your results will be based on what you have set the selection behavior to, via [`setSelectionBehavior()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop)

When you have a list of items, you can specifically get the second column item (if it wasn't selected already):

```
QTableWigetItem *keyItem = table->item(anItem->row(), 1);
QString val = keyItem->text();
```

Comment: same reply to this, if I put this in loop, if we assume that we have 2 columns and 2 rows, it will loop 4 times, but I need to loop only 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QSet` to get all selected rows. Example:

```
  const QList<QTableWidgetItem*> tableItems=widget->selectedItems();
  QSet<int> uniqueRows;
  for(const QTableWidgetItem *item: tableItems)
  {
      uniqueRows.insert(item->row());
  }
```